# Release the processed data in sequence

Tags: f#, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation

I am doing data processing with F#. First I got all files in a directory, then process each file to generate some data structure. Finally I will store the processed data into SQLite. I known that if I using Seq to store the file name and then pipe-forward to Seq.map that will do lazy process for each file. But how about there are so many files that contain all of them in memory is impossible. Then in imperative programming language, I could read one file, process it, store it and release the intermedia data and do next file. Of course F# could do imperative programming, but I want to know if there are some chances to do it in Functional programming style?

```
files
|> Seq.map readFile
|> Seq.map processContent
|> Seq.map storeProcessResult
```

code above shows my opinion. `files` contains a sequence of file names, then I read the content of file, process it into some structure and finally store the result into database. I know that because of the lazy behaviour, file will be read and processed one by one. But when will the final data released?

Comment: are you getting an error? you can process this with recursion. Or just use higher order functions, and open the files with `use`. You can easily process data that will fill 10s of GBs in the database.

Comment: So why does't `Seq` work for you? It's lazy as you say and if the `Seq.map` operation reads the file and the content is then processed by `Seq.fold` you only keep one file in memory at a time.

Comment: @FuleSnabel do you mean that in Seq, every processed data will be released?

Comment: @s952163 no error here. In my opinion, all yield value in seq will keep in the memory until the entire pipe-forward sequence run over. Perhaps I misunderstand at this point.

Comment: this is a very typical workflow and should work. You might need to structure in it a way to make sure to release the file handle in readfile, not keep references to the data in ProcessContent, and most likely use seq.iter for storeProcessResult. GC will take care of it. As we appear to be in the same timezone feel free to join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f

Answer (score 1):

Obviously only you know what happens inside your readFile, processContent and storeProcessResult functions. As @FuleSnabel says in his comment you can map and then use fold (recursion) to process the file.

Here's a simple test you can perform to see the difference in memory consumption: create a List of lists with 10 million elements and sum the list, then create a Seq of lists with 10 million elements, and sum the list. I'm using 64-bit FSI.

This will use about 1GB of memory:

```
let z = [for i in 1..3 -> List.init 10000000 (fun _ -> 1)]
let w = z  |> List.map (fun x -> System.GC.Collect();List.sum x)
```

This will only use a few MB of memory, much less than even one list with 10 million 1s in it:

```
let x = seq {for i in 1..3 -> List.init 10000000 (fun _ -> 1 ) }
let y = x |> Seq.map (fun x -> System.GC.Collect(); List.sum x)
```

This is just one (and probably easy) part in the workflow. If you're opening files, you have to make sure to close them as well, hence my suggestion of [use](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/resource-management-the-use-keyword-%5Bfsharp%5D/) above. However I do recognize that accessing the filesystem, and processing large amounts of data in a lazy sequence might cause some problems, in that case you can always profile it and see where the bottleneck is.

By the way, you don't need to call the GC directly in the code, I just did so the intermediate results don't pollute the memory count in the test.